# Northwind DB for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, northwind

I'm using the Northwind DB for SQL Server.

Both `OrderDetails` and the `Products` tables contains `UnitPrice` for the products. I would have expect that the `UnitPrice` in the `Products` table will be the product's cost and that the `UnitPrice` in the `OrderDetails` table will be the price that the product was sold. On that way the gross profit can be calculated.

**BUT**

The UnitPrice at the order's table is either lower or equal to the UnitPrice at the product's table.

Please assist

Comment: I can't speak to business rules of the fictitious Norhwind company but it is likely the UnitPrice in Products is the list price and the OrderDetails price is the price at which the product was sold, including discounts.

Comment: Thanks,
I'm asking because maybe someone already faced that issue.
The OrderDetails table has another column for discount...
Let's say that productID #9-
The product's UnitPrice is 97
The OrderDetails UnitPrice is 97 at 4 orders and 77.7 at the fifth order.
There is a discount for some of the orders but that's will only lower the price which already lower than the product's table UnitPrice.